# Vscode open classes reference in New tab

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ide, editor

You suppose we used some class in current class and now wen I want to open class reference by holding `ctrl` and pressing left click I expect class reference should be opened in new tab but that show in bottom of class like with below screen shot. However that's not bad but I want to show that in new tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether “Preview Mode” is in effect.

For VScode, to stop files from going into preview mode, and always open a new tab go to File -> Preferences -> Settings (or Ctrl + ,)

And try adding the following to “Users Settings”

"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false

Please include a comma if there’s other settings as it has to be a valid json

Comment: it seems `workbench.editor.enablePreview` is false in settings.json, `{"editor.overviewRulerBorder": false,"markdown.preview.markEditorSelection": false,"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false,"workbench.colorCustomizations": {}}`